# Ryver won't install due to missing libgconf2-4 but it is installed

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, kde, dependencies

My Company recently moved from slack to Ryver, and I wanted to install the desktop app instead of using it through Chromium. I went to the website, downloaded the `.deb` and tried to install but it failed on a dependency check for `libgconf2-4`. Now, here is my issue, **there is no such package** to download, there is a `libgconf-2-4` (with that hyphen) which is already installed, yet, for some reason, it still do not work. I also tried through `gdebi` and it said the dependency is not satisfiable Any ideas? Is there a way to unpack the .deb and change the dependency? Or add an alias to the package I have?

Also, I'm running Kubuntu 19.10 with Plasma Desktop, not running Gnome.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:        19.10
Codename:       eoan

$ sudo gdebi ryver_1.3.2_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package cannot be installed
Dependency is not satisfiable: libgconf2-4

$ apt-cache search libgconf
libgconf-2-4 - GNOME configuration database system (shared libraries)
libgconf2-dev - GNOME configuration database system (development)
libgconf2-doc - GNOME configuration database system (API reference)

$ dpkg -l | grep libgconf
ii  libgconf-2-4:amd64                              3.2.6-5ubuntu3                              amd64        GNOME configuration database system (shared libraries)
ii  libgconf2-dev                                   3.2.6-5ubuntu3                              amd64        GNOME configuration database system (development)
ii  libgconf2-doc                                   3.2.6-5ubuntu3                              all          GNOME configuration database system (API reference)
```

Comment: `libgconf2-4` is a few files https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libgconf2-4/filelist .... Seems to be no conflicts with  libgconf-2-4 : Downloads the 18.04 package http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gconf/libgconf2-4_3.2.6-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb ... and install with gdebi .